# Laravel 5.5 request()->all() doesn't get all the inputs

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.5. I am trying to create a post, but when I request for all() data to die dump from request instance I don't get all the fields printed out.

Here is my code to create the post:

```
   /**

    * Persist new post.

    */
public function store()
{
    $this->validate(request(),[

        'title'=>'required' 
    ]);

        dd(request()->all());

        $path = CreatePhotoThumbnail(request()->file('photo'));

        auth()->user()->addPost(new Posts( [
        'title'=>request('title'),
        'body'=>request('body'),
        'photo'=> $path

    ]));
}
```

All i get in `print_R` is the title only:

```
Array ( [_token] => MhOTEGkR1oDMc50q0FiJmI8JCAeuCRrFCfRHcKkq  [title] => test )
```

Edited:

The form:

```
  <!-- Main (left side) -->

  <section style="margin-top:20px;">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

          <!-- post -->
          <article class="blog-post">


          <div class="post-entry">

          <h2>Create a Blog Post</h2>

          <p>Be as specific as u can:</p>


          <form name="" action="/posts/create" method="post" class="comment-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {{csrf_field()}}
          <div style="display: none;">
          <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="79" />
          <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.1" />
          <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
          <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f79-p64-o1" />
          <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="ebcdc94d2e" />
          </div>
          <div class="row">


          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="title">Post Title</label>
            <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Post Title" name="title">
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="body">Body:</label>
            <textarea name="body" id="body" placeholder="Post body" rows="10"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12" id="drop">
              <label for="photo">Upload a post picture</label>
              <input type="file" id="photo"  name="photo" >
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12"><input type="submit" value="Create Post" class="submit-button" /></div>
          </div>
          </form>


          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0px; margin:0px;">
              @include('layouts.errors')
          </div>
          </article>
          <!-- contact end -->

        </div><!-- end col-md-12 -->
    </div><!-- end row -->

   </section>
   <!-- END Main (left side) -->
```

Comment: Show us the form or AJAX or whatnot that's making this request... and check out your browser's Network inspector to see what's going over the wire.

Comment: Your output shows the array has length = 9, but there are only 7 elements. Seems like the missing 2 would be the `body` and `photo` inputs.

Comment: So, looking at your `dd` output, `array:9` indicates there should be nine elements in the output, and your `title` parameter is missing a `"` at the end. I have a suspicion that it's an issue with your `dd` - can you try `print_r` instead?

Comment: @ceejayoz strange enough... print_r doesn't even print anything...

Comment: You can try `return print_r(request()->all(), true);` IIRC. Should spew it out as the response.

Comment: @ceejayoz Array ( [_token] => MhOTEGkR1oDMc50q0FiJmI8JCAeuCRrFCfRHcKkq [_wpcf7] => 79 [_wpcf7_version] => 4.1 [_wpcf7_locale] => en_US [_wpcf7_unit_tag] => wpcf7-f79-p64-o1 [_wpnonce] => ebcdc94d2e [title] => test )

Comment: @flyingL123 print_r Array ( [_token] => MhOTEGkR1oDMc50q0FiJmI8JCAeuCRrFCfRHcKkq [_wpcf7] => 79 [_wpcf7_version] => 4.1 [_wpcf7_locale] => en_US [_wpcf7_unit_tag] => wpcf7-f79-p64-o1 [_wpnonce] => ebcdc94d2e [title] => test )

Comment: Can you try changing the `body` input name to something else? I'm wondering if it's somehow conflicting with the "body" of the request. Sounds odd but who knows.

Comment: L5.5 has changed the validate method to return the validated data. It's possible that it's (un)intentionally modifying `$request->all()`. Unlikely that this is intentional. Try removing the call to `validate()` and see if you see all the data, or add your missing fields with no rules to your validation rules

Comment: @flyingL123 I did change the body to smth else but I still get the same thing in return

Comment: @BenSwinburne's idea is an interesting one. Try adding `body` to the validation and see if it starts showing up.

Comment: @ceejayoz thinking about it, my reasoning wouldn't explain why the hidden fields like `_wpcf7_locale` are making it through.

Comment: Your form is `multipart/form-data`: try using `Input::all()`.

Comment: @BenSwinburne bang when I add body and photo to validation it's working! It seems on L5.5 validation section determines what will be passed to request()->all()!

Comment: Interesting. Not sure that's intended behaviour. I'll post an answer so others can see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel 5.5 changed the `validate()` method to return validated fields so that you could easily pass valid data to model creation without using `request->only()` for example.

It is possible that it is unintentionally modifying `$request->all()` and as such you're not getting the results you intended.

If you want to get everything, try adding your fields to your validator, even if you don't want to validate them, i.e. without actual rules.

For example

```
$validData = $this->validate(request(),[
    'title'=>'required',
    'body' => ''
]);
```

$validData should contain your fields.

You might also try

```
$this->validate(request()->all() ...
```

Which might then not modify the request object meaning `$request->all()` might work as expected

Comment: After doing a research for the issue I found out that one of the newest Laravel 5.5 features is request->all() returns inputs that are only included in validation instance.

Comment: Interesting. Any chance you can cite your sources for others to read?